# AWS (Amazon web services) - Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services

В общем я задеплоил приложение на Elastic Beanstalk AWS через их оболочку, но мне хотелось бы иметь доступ к командной строке линукса этого сервера на котором лежит мое приложение, никак не могу догнать как к нему подключиться, в гугле не нашел. Если это вообще возможно.

Comment: у вас установлен eb cli?

Comment: Установить установил вот, пытаюсь настроить, не очень понимаю что от меня хотят в пункте 2b (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-advanced.html), в один из выше перечисленных файлов я должен добавить  вот эту команду: export PATH=LOCAL_PATH:$PATH ? Только вместо LOCAL_PATH я должен указать что? Это: ~/Library/Python/3.7/bin ? Или как это все...

Comment: да, там хотят, чтобы вы добавили питон в пути, чтобы в терминале вы могли вызывать программу `python`